# Can I call a non-Muslim as "My Brother"?

Tags: halal-haram, sunnah, islamic-philosophy, non-muslim

If a Muslim lady works with non-Muslims, can she call the males as her brother out of respect.

**Does Islam give her permission to do so?**

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking the [help]. Your question seems unclear please consider editing and elaborating your post (each post has an **edit** link at the bottom make use of this feature) and explain what you mean by a non-Muslim as brother, in what way or context and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in calling a non-Muslim by my brother's word.

exactly the contrary,

it's respectful and appreciated to calling a non-muslim by my brother's word or sir, etc..

and be friendly with him to give him a good picture of the Muslims.

that is what Allah Almighty ordered us to do.

Evidence of this in Surat ([(17) **Al-'Isra'**](http://www.e-quran.com/language/english/english4/r-sura17.html)) Chapter number [**17.53**].

> " Tell My worshipers, that they should say words that are the finest ".

**In Arabic:** (**سورة الإسراء** الآية رقم **53**)

> "وَقُلْ لِعِبَادِي يَقُولُوا الَّتِي هِيَ أَحْسَنُ"

But on the condition, that doesn't exceed the limits stipulated in Islam, between the girl and the non-mahram whether he is a Muslim or not.

**summary**

call non-muslim or Muslim by my brother's word
it's just word to express the respect and appreciation.
and don't cancel the sanctity(Hourma) between of the girl and non-mahram from men.

I hope my answer is clear.